# Getting functions in separate contexts using Rhino

Tags: java, javascript, rhino

I have some code which loads a bunch of functions from a script file and caches the resulting Scriptable scope in memory:

```
Scriptable loadScript(File file)
{
  Context ctx = _contextFactory.enterContext();
  ctx.setOptimizationLevel(9);
  Scriptable scope = ctx.initStandardObjects();
  InputStreamReader reader = new FileReader(file);
  ctx.evaluateReader(scope, reader, scriptPath.getName(), 0, null)
  Context.exit();
  return scope;
}

Scriptable parentScope = loadScript(...);
```

I then have another routine which arbitrarily calls these functions throughout its execution. There may be several instances of these routines running in parallel and I don't want them to be interfering with each other, so for each execution I load a child Scriptable scope and set it's parent scope to the cached scope from the loaded file:

```
Context ctx = _contextFactory.enterContext();
Scriptable childScope = ctx.newObject(parentScope);
childScope.setParentScope(parentScope);
```

To invoke JavaScript functions in Java, I do something like the following:

```
Function f = (Function)parentScope.get(methodName, childScope);
f.call(...);
```

My question regards that last `get()` method. Why, if it's an instance method of Scriptable, does it take another Scriptable object as the second parameter? In other words, what does it do with the Scriptable `this` instance and the one passed in as an argument? The documentation isn't clear on this.

Comment: If I just do `(Function)childScope.get(methodName, childScope)`, it doesn't resolve successfully.